# Accelerometer - Offset correction

Tags: accelerometer, detection, calibration, motion, offset

I'm using the [MMA8453Q](http://www.nxp.com/files/sensors/doc/data_sheet/MMA8453Q.pdf) for motion detection. The accelerometer is mounted such a way that when it is stationary, X & Y axes are at 0g & Z-axis is at 1g.

My usecase is:
A tilt across any axes beyond 45 degree should generate an interrupt.

I have enabled motion detection with threshold 0.707g. For X & Y axes the motion detection works properly & interrupts when tilted beyond 45 degree. But, for Z-axis, even while it is untouched it interrupts as by default it reads 1g.

Is it possible for me to correct this 1g and make it zero-g offset?

The description for the OFF_Z (User offset correction registers) mentions the following:

> The 2’s complement 8-bit value would result in an offset compensation
>   range ±256 mg

And, when I referred the application note [AN4069](http://www.nxp.com/files/sensors/doc/app_note/AN4069.pdf), for calibration, they subtract from 0g,0g & 1g for X, Y & Z axes respectively. This makes me feel suspicious whether I could achieve a tilt detection across Z-axis.

Kindly suggest me how I could achieve my usecase.

Comment: Check pps 13 and 14 of the datasheet. There is a lockout region for z axis, possibly because the device usually has y or x axis oriented vertically. Maybe mounting it rotated would solve the problem. I still do not get how would you think tilt on three axis look like: one of the rotation is undetectable by the accelerometer.

Comment: @VladimirCravero Thanks. But, the Z-lockout region is for orientation detection & not for motion detection. The accelerometer is already mounted, so it is quite impossible for remounting it.

Comment: "The motion configuration has the option of enabling or disabling a high-pass filter to eliminate tilt data (static offset). [...] For details on the freefall and motion detection with specific application examples
and recommended configuration settings, refer to NXP application note AN4070."

Comment: You were just one figure away :) good luck.